# Katz's symbol 兄 for Gauss-Manin connections

Tags: mathematics, terminology, algebraic-geometry

In his famous 1970 paper [1], Nicholas Katz used the character 兄 for the Gauss-Manin connection. I have always been curious about the history behind this symbol.

**Question:** What motivated Katz to use this symbol?

My guess is that it is because, in the previous paper [2] with Oda, they used the letter Д for the Gauss-Manin connection (maybe because Manin is Russian?). Then maybe Oda feels that Д looks like 兄?

Reference:

[1] Katz, Nicholas M. "Nilpotent connections and the monodromy theorem: Applications of a result of Turrittin." Publications Mathématiques de l'IHÉS 39 (1970): 175-232.

[2] Katz, Nicholas M., and Tadao Oda. "On the differentiation of de Rham cohomology classes with respect to parameters." Journal of Mathematics of Kyoto University 8.2 (1968): 199-213.

Comment: The symbol looked like a Japanese character, and a tweet seems to say so in Japanese. The machine translation is (I do not know Japanese): "There are actually quite a few examples of using hiragana, katakana, and kanji in mathematical formulas, which is interesting.
There are many foreign mathematics papers in which Yoneda embedding is denoted by ``yo'', Katz denoted Gauss-Manin connection by ``older brother'', Satake compactification is denoted by ``sa'' and ``sa'', and the Mumford compact There are also papers that use the character ``ma'' to denote chemistry."

Comment: This is the Japanese tweet "https://twitter.com/keisankionwykip/status/1413426168619929601"

Comment: Yes, that symbol is a Chinese character/Japanese Kanji, meaning "older brother." Thank you for the link. I am still wondering why that symbol is used.

Comment: It appears that Katz could have done a postdoc in Japan and he was influenced by the newly learned language. Tadao Oda is a pure Japanese name.